# C# help about writing method for comparing parameters of two objects

Tags: c#

Im trying to write a simple code which will have output text of Car specifications and tell which Car has more HP at the end of program.

```
 public class Engine
    {
    private int cubage;
    private double power;

        public int Cubage
        {
            get { return cubage; }
            set { cubage = value; }                  
        }

        public double Power
        {
            get { return power; }
            set { power = value; }
        }

        public double Power_HP(double power)
        {
            return power * 1.36;
        }
        public Engine(int cubage, double power)
        {
            this.cubage = cubage;
            this.power = power;
        }                           
        }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        private string manufacturer;
        private string model;
        private string color;

        public string Manufacturer
        {
            get { return manufacturer; }
            set { manufacturer = value; }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set { model = value; }
        }

        public string Color
        {
            get { return color; }
            set { color = value; }
        }
        public Body (string manufacturer, string model, string color)
        {
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
            this.model = model;
            this.color = color;
        }
    public class Car
    {
        private Body body;
        private Engine engine;

        public Car(string manufacturer, string model, string bolor, int cubage, double power)
        {
            body = new Body(manufacturer, model, color);
            motor = new Motor(cubage, power);
        }
        public void Printo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Marka:" + sasija.Manufacturer);
            Console.WriteLine("Model:" + sasija.Model);
            Console.WriteLine("Boja:" + sasija.Color);
            Console.WriteLine("Zapremina:" + motor.Cubage);
            Console.WriteLine("Snaga u kW:" + motor.Power);
            /*Console.WriteLine("Snaga u HP" + Motor.Power_HP());*/

        }

        public void Difference() /*This is the method I want to use to show which car has more hp but I dont know how to succesfully compare their Snaga parameters*/
        {
            if (engine.Power > engine.Power)
                Console.WriteLine("Motor prvog auta je snažniji od motora drugog auta");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Motor drugog auta je snažniji od motora prvog auta");

        }
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Car 1:");
            Auto A = new Auto("Audi", "A6", "Black", 2500, 130);
            /* Console.WriteLine("Snaga u HP:" + A.Power_HP(130));*/
            A.Printo();
            Console.WriteLine("Car 2:");
            Auto B=new Auto("BMW", "320D", "Blue",2000,119);
            B.Printo();
            Difference();
            if (130 > 119)
                Console.WriteLine("Motor prvog auta je snažniji od motora drugog auta");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Motor drugog auta je snažniji od motora prvog auta");

            /*Auto.Razlika(130,150);*/                 
           /* Console.WriteLine("Snaga u HP:" + B.Snaga_HP(119));*/
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    }
```

For better understanding of this code I will write translate of my words:
Motor-Engine
Zapremina-Cubage of engine
Marka-Manufacturer of car
Model-Model of car
Boja-color
Ispis-Output text method
Sasija-Frame of car
Razlika= Difference method for telling which car has more hp
I put comments just to block some lines of code to save it for later if needed. I hope you can understand what is my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. You need a method, that compares to cars and prints out some information about the car with higher HP?

Comment: Yes, I want to print message which car has more hp. But I need a method for that. I dont know how to write method for that.

Comment: in this kind of class models, you'd make `Razlika` a function, passing in a second instance of `Auto` to compare against (currently you are comparing against itself), and return a boolean: `public bool Razlika(Auto second_car) { return this.Snaga > second_car.Snaga; }`, then call like `var result = A.Razlika(B);`. Is that what you mean? It would require to expose `Snaga` as a property of the `Auto` class, because `motor` is private in your current design.

Comment: @dlatikay: I think your solution is right. Post this as answer, that Pavlony can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @dlatikay I did that and I get error messages for`var rezultat=A.Razlika(B);`Erorr messages are :Cannot asing void to an implicity-typed variable  and No overload for method `Razlika`takes 1 arguments.

Comment: The basic requirements will be: 1. Expose the Motor as a public property of the Auto class 2. Create either or both a static method that takes two Autos and outputs the comparison result, and/or an instance method that takes one auto and outputs the comparison results with the instance. Translating your code to English would help people a lot.

Comment: @RufusL Problem is that I dont know how to make that method for two Autos and output comparison results. I translated it to English.

Comment: Got it, posted one way to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic requirements will be:

1. Expose the Motor as a public property of the Auto class
2. Create either or both a static method that takes two Autos and outputs the comparison result, and/or an instance method that takes one auto and outputs the comparison results with the instance.

---

**Skip this if you know about string interpolation and ternary operator**

It should be noted that in my code I'm using some C# 6.0 features, like "string interpolation". When you see a string like this: `$"The motor of {first} is more powerful than {second}"`, it's the same thing as: `string.Format("The motor of {0} is more powerful than {1}", first, second)`

Also, if you're not familiar with the ternary operator, when you see something like this:

```
var firstIsGreater = (first == null)
    ? second == null
    : first.Motor == null
        ? second.Motor == null
        : first.Motor.Power > second.Motor.Power;
```

Its the same thing as:

```
bool firstIsGreater;
if (first == null)
    firstIsGreater = (second == null);
else if (first.Motor == null)
    firstIsGreater = (second.Motor == null);
else
    firstIsGreater = (first.Motor.Power > second.Motor.Power);
```

---

**Here are some changes I would make**

The properties that are simply backed by private fields can be made into auto-properties:

```
public class Frame
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public Frame(string make, string model, string color)
    {
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

Also, horsepower can be a calculated field based on Power:

```
public class Motor
{
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public double Power { get; set; }
    public double Horsepower { get { return Power * 1.36; } }

    public Motor(int volume, double power)
    {
        Volume = volume;
        Power = power;
    }
}
```

Then make the `Motor` property `public` on the `Auto` class, so it's properties can be accessed. Note that I also overwrote the `ToString` method so we have a friendly way to display the Auto name.

The main change here, though, is the addition of the two `ShowComparison` methods. One of them is `static`, which means you don't need to use an Auto instance to compare two cars, and the other is an instance method, which compares the current instance with some other Auto:

```
public class Auto
{
    public Frame Frame { get; set; }
    public Motor Motor { get; set; }

    public Auto(string make, string model, string color, int volume, double power)
    {
        Frame = new Frame(make, model, color);
        Motor = new Motor(volume, power);
    }

    public void DisplayDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Make:" + Frame.Make);
        Console.WriteLine("Model:" + Frame.Model);
        Console.WriteLine("Color:" + Frame.Color);
        Console.WriteLine("Volume:" + Motor.Volume);
        Console.WriteLine("Power (kW):" + Motor.Power);
        Console.WriteLine("Horsepower:" + Motor.Horsepower);
    }

    public void ShowComparison(Auto other)
    {
        ShowComparison(this, other);
    }

    public static void ShowComparison(Auto first, Auto second)
    {
        var firstIsGreater = (first == null)
            ? second == null
            : first.Motor == null
                ? second.Motor == null
                : first.Motor.Power > second.Motor.Power;

        Console.WriteLine((firstIsGreater)
            ? $"The motor of {first} is more powerful than {second}"
            : $"The motor of {second} is more powerful than {first}");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Frame.Make} {Frame.Model}";
    }
}
```

Now, you can show the difference in three ways, described below:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Auto 1:");
    Auto A = new Auto("Audi", "A6", "Crna", 2500, 130);
    A.DisplayDetails();
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Auto 2:");
    Auto B = new Auto("BMW", "320D", "Plava", 2000, 119);
    B.DisplayDetails();
    Console.WriteLine();

    // These all output the same text
    Auto.ShowComparison(A, B);
    A.ShowComparison(B);
    B.ShowComparison(A);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This is so much helpful! Thank you very much kind man! I have a stupid question, I just got in C# programming. What I replace first & second with? Do I just type A instead of first or what?

Comment: `first` and `second` are input parameters to the `static` `ShowComparison` method. The first example is the one that calls this method directly(`Auto.ShowComparison(A, B);`). This method also gets called indirectly from the `instance` version, like in the second and third examples. In the second example: `A.ShowComparison(B);`, if you follow the code, that method internally calls the static method with: `ShowComparison(this, other);`, where `this` is the `A` instance and `other` is the `B` instance. Hope that helps?

Comment: In short, you can call `Auto.ShowComparison` with two `Auto` instances. `first` will be one of your `Autos` and `second` would be the other one.

Comment: Yes, I modified my code by your instructions. Thank you very much! Do you have any ideas so I can make more out of this program?